# How do I add shape to InkCanvas at mouse position using MouseDown event WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mouseevent, inkcanvas

I use the following code which allows me to set the size and adds the square to the inkcanvas when I click a button. It adds the shape to the top left of the canvas. I would like to be able to add the shape to the canvas at the location where I click the mouse on the canvas.

Currently I get the mouse position:

```
private void inkCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    cursorCoords.Content = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);

    // Get the x and y coordinates of the mouse pointer.
    System.Windows.Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
    pX = position.X;
    pY = position.Y;
}
```

When the shape tool is selected (tool == 3) draw a square at the position where I clicked the inkcanvas. This doesn't work however and just draws a standard pen stroke. Also when I click somewhere on the inkcanvas it doesn't update a labels contents to the current position coordinates.

```
private void inkCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (tool == 3)
    {
        coordstest.Content = pX + '-' + pY;
        switch (chosenShape)
        {
            case "square":
                Stroke oS = NewRectangle(pY, pX, size * 4, size * 4);

                DrawingAttributes attribs = new DrawingAttributes();
                attribs.Color = shapeColour;//Colors.LimeGreen;
                attribs.Height = 5.0;
                attribs.Width = 5.0;
                attribs.FitToCurve = false;

                oS.DrawingAttributes = attribs;
                inkCanvas.Strokes.Add(oS);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`tool` is the tool selected, stored in a byte as 1, 2 or 3 for pen, background colour and shape.
`shapeChosen` is a string, there will be the option of square, star, circle, triangle.

Is there something I'm missing in the inkcanvas mouse down event handler to make the above happen? How do I stop the pen drawing when I want to place a shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case `MouseDown` event don't work, because is handled by the InkCanvas and it not being bubbled up, so try these solutions:

I. Use the [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Specify handledEventsToo as true to have the provided handler be invoked for routed event that had already been marked as handled by another element along the event route.

Example:

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyInkCanvas.AddHandler(InkCanvas.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(InkCanvas_MouseDown), true);
}

private void InkCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

II. Try using [`PreviewMouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.previewmousedown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of *`MouseDown`*, because PreviewMouseDown is tunneled event, and his runned first, before bubble events.

Comment: This worked but I have a couple of related problems if you care to look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011418/shape-not-drawing-at-mouse-position-on-inkcanvas-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: @crm: Okay, I'll try look.